# AIX special keys

Tags: bash, centos, aix, vt100

I connect to AIX 5.3 through ssh from Centos 6. Shells on AIX and Centos are bash. When I press "Home", "End", "PgUp", "PgDn" in shell, bash outputs tilde (~) and cursor is not moving to end or begin of string. How can I get these buttons work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your Readline initialization file (default `~/.inputrc`):

```
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[8~": end-of-line
```

If you want to figure out what characters are being generated by a key sequence, one way is to use `od -c`, type the key sequence, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>. Doing this for <kbd>Home</kbd> looks like this for me:

```
$ od -c

0000000 033   [   7   ~  \n
0000005
```

Comment: Thank you for inputrc. It helps. I put to this file lines:
    "\e[1~": beginning-of-line
    "\e[4~": end-of-line
    "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
    "\e[6~": end-of-history
    "\e[7~": beginning-of-line
    "\e[8~": end-of-line